# Turning OFF CHECK_POLICY by default

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We moved from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005. The client software, which I can not change, creates a user without option

```
CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

After creating a user, I have to run the command

```
ALTER LOGIN username WITH CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

Disable the policy, as recommended, I can not.

Is it possible to disable the default `CHECK_POLICY` that without her `CREATE LOGIN` user created with `CHECK_POLICY = OFF`?

Comment: Why do you upgrade from an ancient version to another ancient version? We had 3 new versions since your "new" version.

Comment: I would assume that the answer to that question is because the software vendor only supports up to SQL 2005.  It's very common.

Comment: To mrdenny: Software vendor does not consider this a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do it with a DDL Trigger that captures the DDL event for `CREATE LOGIN`

```
CREATE TRIGGER PolicyStuff
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_LOGIN
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginType)[1]','nvarchar(100)') = 'SQL Login'
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000) = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')) + ' WITH CHECK_POLICY = OFF;';
    EXEC(@sql);
END
GO

CREATE LOGIN foo WITH PASSWORD='C-mplex654Password', CHECK_POLICY=ON;
GO
SELECT SL.name, SL.is_policy_checked FROM sys.sql_logins SL WHERE SL.name = 'foo'
GO
DROP LOGIN foo
GO
```

Comment: Were DDL triggers available in SQL 2005?

Comment: @mrdenny: yes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Cool. It's been a while since I've had to do anything exciting with SQL 2005. Couldn't for the life of me remember.  They would have been my suggestion as well.

Comment: I'm nowhere in the documentation does not find any mention of what CHECK_POLICY not be turned off by default. But it seems that the way it is.

Comment: @Arty: I looked all over too. Including various MS SQL Server blogs. It can't be set globally from what I read.

Answer (score 0):

these wont work if you have created your login with MUST_CHANGE and user didn't change the default password otherwise its working fine...